# Filter Solr Facet by language

Tags: solr, search-facet

I am trying to create facets in a multi language solution and facing couple of problems.

1. How to filter facets by language selection. If you see the screenshot below, the facets are getting displayed but all language items are displayed. Instead, i need only specified language facets.
   [image]
2. I need the facets results in blocks like [facet value, count]. But as you can see in the above image, it is comma separated and not in blocks. How to get that?

Here is the solr query i am using.

```
https://localhost:8983/solr/sitecore_master_index/select?q=_template%3A3F60E9876EB94FCC9D11679271B8AD3C&facet.field=articleassetclass_s&rows=0&facet=true
```

Comment: Did you try adding the required language to the solr query?

Comment: @Gatogordo: Yes, I did add the required language like "_language=en". But that is filtering the results and not filtering facets.

Comment: I think each category type in your articleaseetclass category should have multiple fields. One field should have key which should be in English only like Obligation and other field should be value field which should be having its multilingual version like Obbligazionario. As such, when you get facets, it will return results on key which is in English only.

Comment: @Ghanendra: Thanks for responding. I don't know how to find the key. You may be right that the above are values to the facet field articleassetclass and not to language. For ex: Obbligazionario is Italian version for Obligations.